# Request for help with two reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

- Given two graphs one needs to decide if one of them has a subgraph isomorphic to the other.
- Given a subset of a graph one needs to decide if the induced subgraph is  triangle free.

Can someone kindly help prove that both of these are NP-Complete?

Comment: What makes you think they are NP-complete? What did you try, or what research have you done?

Comment: The first one is a [standard, well-known reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem); the second is not **NP**-complete.

Comment: @Juho I am told that these are NP-Complete. I tried various kinds of reductions but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks! Can you kindly say how to solve triangle freeness in polynomial time?

Comment: @guest The first one is, but there are many simple algorithms for the second problem that run in polynomial time.

Comment: @guest Just look for a triangle. No smartness required.

Comment: @Juho Okay - Given a subset of a graph and asking if the induced subgraph on it is triangle free - is this NP-Complete? (..I am told that there is a reduction from independent set apparently!...)

Comment: Please edit your question to include *precisely* the problems you are interested in, and what the question is. You can't hope to meaningfully solve a problem or to "try various kinds of reductions" if you don't even know the problem is! We also won't solve your homework for you here, we want you to learn as well.

Comment: @Juho I didn't think that the two questions are different - it looks the same to me (I still edited it to reflect closely my original reference) - does it change anything?

Comment: I have a feeling the second problem is still not formulated the way it was intended. Maybe you can copy the problem statement exactly to clear up any confusion?

Comment: @Juho Agreed: for the current problem statement, just check every triple of vertices in the given set to see if they're a triangle.

Comment: A subset
S
of vertices in an undirected graph
G
is called
triangle-free
if the induced graph
G
S
has no 3-cycles (aka triangles). That is, for every three vertices
u; v; w
in
V
, at least
one of the three edges
uv
,
uw
,
vw
is absent from
G
.
Reduce Independent Set to this Triangle-Free problem

Comment: This is exact statement - does it change anything?

Comment: @guest If that's the exact question, it's a really bad question. But I think they're trying to say this: reduce the problem "Does $G$ have an independent set of size at least $k$?" to the problem "Is there a set $S\subseteq V(G)$ with size at least $k$ such that $G[S]$ is triangle-free?" I can believe the latter problem is **NP**-complete.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think this is the "induced subgraph with property $P$" problem, which is NP-complete for any property $P$ that holds for arbitrarily large graphs, does not hold for all graphs, and is hereditary, i.e. holds for all induced subgraphs of $G$ whenever it holds for $G$. These are results by Yannakakis from the late 70s.

Comment: @DavidRicherby How do you see that this is NP-Complete - "Is there an induced sub-graph of size $k$ which is triangle free?"   [...won't even a brute force search over all subgraphs of size $k$ be polynomial?...]

Comment: @guest No. There are roughly $|V^k|$ such subgraphs but $k$ is a part of the input, represented in binary, so $k$ could be as much as $2^{\text{input length}}$. This means that the "check all the possibilities" algorithm isn't polynomial.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I would have thought that $\vert V \vert ^k$ is "polynomial" since its polynomial in the size of the graph. So how do you prove that this is NP-complete?

Comment: @guest That's an easy mistake to make (and a common one, too). But I just explained why it's a mistake.